# How to calculate degrees of freedom for glmmTMB model with mixed effects?

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, glmmtmb

I'm using glmmTMB model with mixed effects and beta distribution and I'm wondering is there a way to count degrees of freedom of my model variables (they are not in my model output)?